# How to preconfigure the debug log level filter in IntelliJ Idea (PhpStorm/WebStorm) when running React Native

Tags: react-native, debugging, intellij-idea, logging, phpstorm

I have a React Native project I'm running from PhpStorm using a run configuration, which launches Metro, launch-ios, Chrome debug etc. which all works fine.

The JS logs appear in the console of the IDE under the name of "iOS Build " but the default filter doesn't include debug logs. I can click "Filter > Debug" and turn it on but then it resets back to unticked ever time I restart the debugger. Presently I am restarting the debugger a lot because I am debugging the first-boot cycle of the app.

[image]

In the documentation for other run/debug configs, IntelliJ has log options (which they are recently changing to a separate panel). I think you can preset the filters there:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html#d3ebaf91

However for the React Native plugin, the run/debug config pane doesn't include any options for drilling down into the logs.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2022.1/react-native.html#ws_react_native_run_and_debug

[image]

What I want is for the Debug Level to be or remain ticked as well by default when I run the configuration.

Is there some configuration file perhaps with extra options that are not represented in this plugins GUI?

Can I get the IDE to remember the state of the Debug pane generally? For example also I keep having to drag the columns around each time to my preferred layout.

I know I could view the logs in Chrome, but I prefer headless mode and an IDE-centric workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug, tracked at [WEB-39848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39848/Filter-in-debug-console-is-reset-when-debugger-is-restarted); please vote for it to be notified when it's fixed

Comment: Thanks Lena that's good to know. I have voted for it.